# Position item on top

Tags: css, positioning

I'm having a little bit of issues with the placing of objects on my site...

All I want is to place the [coloured items ùnder the main container](http://www.chirowuustwezel.be/new/index.php?page=home). So the `navigation_groups` div should be placed under the `main_container`.

```
<div class="navigation_groups">
     // Navigation              
</div>
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="main_container_top"></div>
    <div class="main_container_middle"></div>
    <div class="main_container_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried to play with `position`, but for some reason, if I add a `absolute` or `relative` property, the links in de `navigation_groups` disappear... How can I solve this?

The z-index property didn't work either...

Comment: Do the div boundaries show up when you use developer tools? That usually helps. (With absolute, you can have problems where the parent element is really small and overflow is hidden. So, these tools help!)

Comment: Is the problem now fixed on the site you link to?  If so, can you paste the original code into the question so that it will be useful to others in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you put the menu on the back, it become non-responsive since the content div completely covers the menu space..

You need to re-style your elements a bit differently..

```
.main_container {
    margin: -90px 0 0 132px;
    position: relative;
}

.main_container_top {
    /*whatever you have but change the positioning of the background image to*/
    background-position: 0 10px;
}

.main_container_middle {
    /*whatever you have but change the positioning of the background image to*/
    background-position: 0 10px;
    /*and the padding to*/
    padding: 30px 0 30px 56px;
}

.main_container_bottom {
    /*whatever you have but change the positioning of the background image to*/
    background-position: -7px 0;
}

.navigation_groups {
    /*change the following to*/
    position: relative;
    z-index:0;
}
```

what we actually did, besides removing the negative z-index is push the element 124px to the right and fix all affected elements by correcting their padding and background-positioning by the same amount..

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did all the changes you asked for. The links are back, but the menu-items are still placed in front of the main container :(

Comment: @Michiel, put `position: relative;` on the `.main_container` as well.. updated answer..

Comment: Yep, did found it myself in the mean time! Thanks a million for your input and solving my question!

Answer (score 0):

When using `position:absolute`, you need to declare `position:relative` on a parent item to provide a zero-point of reference for the positioning, otherwise you end up using the BODY as a reference point.

Without seeing your CSS it's hard to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: I did provide a link to the site, no? http://www.chirowuustwezel.be/new/index.php?page=home

Comment: Now, the items are placed behind the main container (as it should be) but the links in the navigation are gone... and that should be fixed!